# Fragment already added, dialogfragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, illegalstateexception, fragmentmanager

I have a dialogfragment which displays fine but some time when I try to display it I keep getting `IllegalStateException`

Below is the logcat

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: SelectPlan04Dialog{fa768dc #7 }
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1893)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:760)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2595)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2382)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2337)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2244)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:702)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6679)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)]
```

This is the code as how I am calling the dialog

```
if (selectPlan04Dialog == null) {
    selectPlan04Dialog = new SelectPlan04Dialog();
}
if (!selectPlan04Dialog.isVisible() && !selectPlan04Dialog.isAdded()) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable("moduleApi", module);
    selectPlan04Dialog.setArguments(b);                
    selectPlan04Dialog.show(getCurrentActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "");
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Fragment transactions are asynchronous.

It is possible that you have two or more calls to this code before the fragment transactions are executed. `!selectPlan04Dialog.isVisible() & !selectPlan04Dialog.isAdded()` condition is true and `show()` schedules another fragment transaction to execute later.

Some options for fixing this:

- Create a new dialog every time and don't try to reuse an old one
- Change asynchronous fragment transactions to synchronous with a call to fragment manager `executePendingTransactions()`

Comment: but is it ok to call executePendingTransactions ? I am experiencing ANR because of to many calls to show

Answer (score 9):

```
 modalBottomSheet.show(supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(modalBottomSheet),ModalBottomSheet.TAG)
```

**Сall like this**

Comment: This actually seems to work well

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, I have tried clicking "Show dialog fragment" by tapping the button multiple times and quickly.

```java
try {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment oldFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("wait_modal");
    
    if (oldFragment != null && oldFragment.isAdded())
        return;
    
    if (oldFragment == null && !please_wait_modal.isAdded() && !please_wait_modal.isVisible()) {
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
        please_wait_modal.show(fm,"wait_modal");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: not working for progress dialog fragment